# C# Bitmap Image

Tags: c#

I created an image with bitmap:

```
Graphics GFX = CreateGraphics();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\C#\slideplace.png");
GFX.DrawImage(bitmap, 319, 69, 149, 20);
```

I have two questions:

- How can I get `GFX` location because I want to make it movable (like picturebox.location).
- Which is the image's event when the mouse is over it, clicked and hold, like a picturebox event (mousedown and also for mouseup).

Answer (score 2):

`Graphics` and `Bitmap` have no UI component so they have no `Location` property.  You need to use a `PictureBox` or some other UI control to render your Bitmap

Comment: So, if I create a button image with bitmap, I can't make it movable, can I?

Comment: nope.  You can use a PictureBox (or other control) to display the Bitmap, and then make the control movable.

Comment: I created it with picture box, but my button is round and around it, it appears the form's color because the picture box's color is transparent. I don't want this anymore. I want only the button without form's color around it (inside the picture box's square).

Comment: try to figure it out.  if you can't then start a new question here on SO.